# android - Moto G mobile shows offline in the devices list in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device-driver

I am trying to connect the Moto G device to Eclipse in Windows XP 32-bit machine.It shows in the devices List but as offline and in unknown status. 
I have installed USB driver. I turned on USB debugging on the phone and able to connect my device as MTP or PTP,it is detecting as removable hardware in the system but in eclipse it shows as offline.

```
Tried the following things
```

> Downloaded the Adb driver Installer from here http://adbdriver.com/downloads/
>   tried to installing driver using it, it says driver already installed.
>
> Then restarted the adb and checked, then restarted the device & checked nothing worked out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any application you build is working in emulator? Cause you have tried everything which is needed..
Did you specified android:minSdkVersion in your application? The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. So you can try first testing in emulator.If everything is working fine in that than sure there is problem with device. And last thing you can check in your device Settings -> Security -> Check Unknown Sources option. Even check Allow debugging mode.Hope it helps.